# How to remove multiple focuses from password field in android

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout

I wrote a code to check password field is empty or not .I set a error message when password field is empty.

Then I run my application . I could see multiple focuses on the password field when I tried to submit the form without filling the password field.

This is my code,

```
@InjectView(R.id.et_password)
EditText mEditTextPassword;

@OnClick(R.id.btn_sign_up)
public void signUp() {
     if(!validatePassword(mEditTextPassword.getText().toString())){
         mEditTextPassword.setError("Please enter password");
         mEditTextPassword.requestFocus();

     }
}
```

This is my method,

```
private boolean validatePassword(String text) {
     if (text.length() != 0) {
          return true;
     } else {
          return false;
     }
}
```

This is my password field in my layout file,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
         app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

         <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/et_password"
               style="@style/EditTextStyle"
               android:hint="@string/hint_password"
               android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now I want to remove this multiple focuses on password field.

This is my screenshot,

[image]

Have any ideas about this ?

Comment: What are multiple focuses?

Comment: @f1sh : I could see two red dots on the password field. I think they are came with the error message.

Comment: Still no idea what you mean by that..

Comment: show screenshot

Comment: @MuratK. : I try to submit a form without filling the password field. Before it I write a code to check password field is empty or not . If the password filed is empty, the code brings me an error message .

Comment: @Androider : See my updates.

Comment: may be removing " mEditTextPassword.requestFocus(); " might help?

Comment: did you solved you problem?, check answer.

Comment: +1 for the fact that I learned 2 unrelated things from your post (Butterknife and TextInputLayout), sorry this comment isn't more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Set your error message just for TextInputLayout only &
remove it from editText .

Thanks